# How can i create a layout that behaves like an edit text view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

//still a learner :-)

I'm trying to create a layout that behaves like an edit text view, except I'm populating it with small xml layouts instead of text, these will be added dynamically eventually but for now I'm just using the include tag in xml to see how it reacts.

what I'm trying to achieve essentially is a keyboard that, instead of single characters, is made up of cards with a word and picture.

When a card is selected it should show up in a view, we'll call this the cardview. The cardview should display each card in the same way that text would be displayed in an edit text view, ie; each selected card should be displayed next to the last, and when it reaches the end of the cardview it should start placing the cards below, just like a long line of text in an edit text view.

everything I've tried has failed one of these conditions, the closest I can tell is a linear layout, this would of course place each card next to the last but doesn't respect the end of the view, the cards just keep going.

so my question is do I need to do some fancy programming to create this viewgroup to mimic an edit text view? off the top of my head maybe by measuring the screen size and creating a custom layout of some sort that allows X many cards before starting a new line, (and if so can anyone offer me a starting point?) or is there an easier way, something I've missed, by using a nested viewgroup or some kind of table layout?

any and all replies welcome, and thanks for your time

Comment: What about a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager?

Comment: never used one before, just googling it now looks very promising thank you,